# golang program running fine outside of docker, but exiting with 0 when dockerized

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    expose:
      - '8080'
    container_name: 'api'
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true    
    networks:
      - api-net

  db:
    build: ./db
    expose:
      - '27017'
    container_name: 'mongo'
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - api-net

networks:
  api-net:
    driver: bridge
```

and the Dockerfile for the api container is as follows:

```
FROM iron/go:dev
RUN mkdir /app
COPY src/main/main.go /app/
ENV SRC_DIR=/app
ADD . $SRC_DIR
RUN go get goji.io
RUN go get gopkg.in/mgo.v2
# RUN cd $SRC_DIR; go build -o main
CMD ["go", "run", "/app/main.go"]
```

If I run the code for main.go outside of a container it runs as expected, however if I try to run the container as part of docker-compose I get an exit 0. I have seen other threads on stackoverflow that have suggested using stdin_open and tty, but these have not helped. I have also tried creating an .env file in the same directory I issue docker-compose up from with `COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=8000` in it and this has not worked either. I am looking for helped and suggestions as to what I need to do in order for my api container to stay up.

I know that `--verbose` can be issued with docker-compose, however I'm not sure what I should be looking for in the output that this produces.

Comment: Maybe paste here output from `--verbose` log as well.

Comment: 1. run command "docker ps -a" to get a list of all containers
2. From this list get the container id of your exited container
3. Run the command "docker logs -f {container id from step 2}
Check if you get any useful troubleshooting information from logs

Comment: It's better to build the Go binary elsewhere (like CI/CD if you have any) and then copy it into your container, rather than trying to build it in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Stupid question, but why are you using the iron/go version image of golang instead of the official repo https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/

Comment: Any logs? the exit code 0 comes from the main.go check the code maybe different config out of the container. btw use multi stage builds to improve the process

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed to get to the bottom of this, in my code which worked outside of a container I had:

```
http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", mux)
```

the fix was to simply remove localhost such that I now have:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
```